# How to add values to a table using the parameters of: table name, column names, and value names in the C # code?

Tags: c#, sql

I try to insert values into a table using function parameters. I get an error:

> Syntax error in sentence INSERT INTO.

Where's the mistake?

Here is code in C #:

```
public static int InsertWithParam(string table, string column1, string column2, string value1, string value2)
{
    string str = "INSERT INTO" + @table + "(@column1, @column2) VALUES (@value1, @value2)";

    try
    {
        using (OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(connectinstring)) 
        {
            using (var command = new OleDbCommand(str, connect))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@column1", value1));
                command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@column2", value2));

                connect.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
         Console.WriteLine(e.Message); 
    }
    return 0;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string table = "Pupils";

    string column1 = "ID";
    string column2 = "FirstName";

    string value1 = "123456789";
    string value2 = "Abc";

    InsertWithParam(table, column1, column2, value1, value2);

}
```

Comment: I think `@table` is supposed to be just `table`. Be careful, you are vulnerable to SQL Injection. And column names cannot be parameterized. And you're not adding the value parameters.

Comment: You should absolutely not be doing SQL like this, you are vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Change @table to the tables name.  I am not sure if you can use parameterised variables for that or not, either way you need to define what @table is.

The query should look something like this.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Table (col1, col2) VALUES (@v1, @v2)";
```

Comment: Your hunch is correct, you are not able to use parameters for table or column names in SQL

Comment: Also needs to change `@column1` to `@value1` in the parameterisation steps.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are going about this is not only *extremely* vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, but also really bad design.  You should **never** concatenate strings to make a query.

Consider an alternative approach like creating classes that represent all the queries needed on a specific table.

For example, a Pupils table should have a class representing the actions you need to perform on that data (Insert, Get, etc).  That way you are explicitly calling the *appropriate* class, which makes your code more clear and concise and you wont expose yourself to SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Is it really better to save a few lines of code, at the risk of exposing your application to *serious* security concerns?

Comment: The "values" in the OP ***are*** parameterised are they not?  And if the table and column names come from the app rather than a human user, that's fine *(they just need substituted into the string, those can't be variables)*.

Comment: @MatBailie the values are indeed parameterised.  Take a look at the context of the OP's code though, it is hardcoded to only accept two columns/values no matter what the table is.  99.9% of the time it is a bad idea to build SQL queries from concatenated strings, regardless if they are user input or not.  We do not know the ultimate intent for this code, I assume OP is getting the dynamic values from somewhere other than a hardcoded string.  This is a huge learning opportunity for someone who clearly is not aware of better designs/options or the potential security risks.

Comment: @MatBailie I also realized I redundantly told the OP to parameterize the values which they are already doing.  I removed that bit from my blurb, thanks!

Comment: I still strongly disagree with the statement `You should never concatenate strings to make a query.`  I've been architect on a product where ***all*** application based queries were driven by concatenation of strings, driven by meta-data.  It was performent, worked cross platform, and was secure.  The alternative approach that you suggest is valid, but dynamic SQL is still equally valid.  *(This is just a weak example of dynamic SQL.)*

Answer (score 0):

Building SQL ***code*** by concatenating strings isn't necessarily a problem, whatever people here say.  There are caveats though:

1. Every ***data*** value should be parameterised
2. Table names, field names, etc, can't be parameters, they need directly substituting
3. Anything directly substituted in should be rigorously sanitised
4. Pretty much never let user input be used as anything other than data

That gives the following amendments to your code...

```
public static int InsertWithParam(string table, string column1, string column2, string value1, string value2)
{
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Substitute in the table and column names, hard code parameter names
    -- Ensure adequate white space between names, etc
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    string.Format("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}, {2}) VALUES (@value1, @value2)", table, column1, column2);

    try
    {
        using (OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(connectinstring)) 
        {
            using (var command = new OleDbCommand(str, connect))
            {
                --------------------------------------------------------------------
                -- Reference the hard coded parameter names during parameterisation
                --------------------------------------------------------------------
                command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@value1", value1));
                command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@value2", value2));

                connect.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
         Console.WriteLine(e.Message); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

They're the minimum changes, I'm not saying I like everything else.  I'd use a dictionary rather than a hard coded list of parameters, I wouldn't always returning zero, etc, etc ;)

Comment: I am very grateful for your help!

Answer (score -2):

Two mistakes I noticed:

1) If your column data types are non numeric, you need to wrap the values in single quotes.

2) There should be a single space between INSERT INTO and Table name

Correct statement is:

```
string str = string.Format("INSERT INTO {0} (@column1, @column2) VALUES ('{1}', '{2}')", table, value1, value2);
```

Comment: If anything, the values are the items that should be parameterised rather than substituted.  This is a more dangerous approach than the OP.

Comment: This is still vulnerable to SQL injection.  It is not dynamic, what happens when  a different table has more columns? And is still not addressing the main problem with OP's bad design